# What does the tag {scope} mean?

Tags: discussion, tagging

The [6 questions currently listed under the tag {scope}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope) *mostly* refer to the [tikz-pgf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf)-related `scope` environment. However, it could easily be confused with the scope of a group within which certain (re)definitions are considered local. I mention *mostly* since the most recent 2 referencing something akin to grouping.

Which is it? Which should it be? Should it be at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest to rename the tag to [scopes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scopes) or [scoping](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scoping).

Besides that, I don't see a problem with the tag appearing in different contexts. It means a concept which could be used in TikZ and basic TeX. We can combine it with the matching tags [tikz-pgf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf) and [tex-core](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tex-core), if the question is about specific scoping. Very similar, for example, to using the [arrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arrow) tag which is commonly combined with [tikz-pgf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf), [pstricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pstricks), [xypic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xypic), [amsmath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amsmath) or whatever, though there's an `arrow` library in TikZ: no need for tags such as [tikz-pgf-arrows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf-arrows) or [tikz-pgf-scopes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf-scopes).

Since up to 5 tags are possible, a tag doesn't need a unique meaning, so we don't need to change the tag (besides renaming).

I would keep the tag since it represents an important concept.

Comment: I wouldn't call it 'scopes', since it is a mass term that should be singular.  Assuming it does have multiple uses, we need a reasonable tag wiki summary that covers both.

Comment: Could this be implemented?

Comment: I actually see there's a [tag:grouping] already, so should I pose a new question regarding a tag synonym? Your thoughts

Comment: @Werner I changed [tag:scope] to [tag:scoping]. Yes, it's similar to [tag:grouping]. I guess it's hard to decide which should be the master tag - while scoping is probably more generally used in CS, grouping is widely used in TeX. A meta question could clarify for us.